# NODE JS API ENCODE � to string

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have a problem with this [API](http://194.141.118.43:3000/stations).

The filed `NAME_CYR` display � and I don't know how to fix that ?

```
    // Create express app
var express = require("express")
var app = express()
var mysql = require('mysql')
var express = require("express")
var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())

// Server port
var HTTP_PORT = 6000

var pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host: '192.168.0.10',
  user: 'UName',
  port: '3333',
  password: 'Pass',
  database: 'DBName'
});

var ardaforecast = '';
var stations = '';


app.route('/')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    // omitted
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*', 'Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    const id = req.query.id;

    pool.query(`CALL Get_Alert_levels_Station(${id});`, function (error, result) {
      if (error)
      return res.status(500).json({ error: "Грешна заявка. Опитай отново !"})
      ardaforecast = result;
      res.json({ ardaforecast })
    });
  });

  app.route('/stations')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    // omitted
    res.set({ 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*', 'Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');

    pool.query(`SELECT * FROM sel_alert_level s;`, function (error, result) {
      if (error)
      return res.status(500).json({ error: "Грешна заявка. Опитай отново !"})
      stations = result;
      res.json({ stations })
    });
  });

// Start server
app.listen(HTTP_PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server running on port %PORT%".replace("%PORT%", HTTP_PORT))
});

pool.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log(err.code); // 'ER_BAD_DB_ERROR'
});

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.status(404);
});
```

Is there a way to convert these � to Cyrillic ?

When I use heidiSQL or MySQL Workbench everything is fine. But when I write this query on `Stations` page:

```
SELECT * FROM sel_alert_level s;
```

The field `NAME_CYR` show as �..

I trying to execute query like this:

```
SELECT Map_code, NAME_IME, CONVERT(NAME_CYR USING cp1251), Alertlevelwebsite, CODENUM FROM sel_alert_level s;
```

But this not work for me. Is there a way to see the data on the field `NAME_CYR` ?

Comment: � is the replacement character for invalid characters, so your input has erroneous characters or you've read the string incorrectly, for example using wrong charset

Comment: I use res.set({ 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }); What is correct charset for windows-cp-1251 do you know ?

Comment: What is the charset of your MySQL connection? You definitely should output JSON as UTF-8, but you need to make sure the data from the MySQL connection is also UTF-8 (even if your database or table charset might be something Cyrillic-specific).

Comment: of course cp1251 can't represent all Unicode characters. Why on earth do you use cp1251 these days

Comment: On this field NAME_CYR in the database the charset is utf8mb4..

Comment: I don't know why I see � if the field NAME_CYR is utf8mb4 and the API charset is UTF8... The data in field NAME_CYR is in Bulgarian (Cyrillic) language..